# Информация по готовым функциям, методам и свойствам JS (сборка уже готовых методов и свойств)

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, есть ли документация по JS, по типу как на JQuery? Я не про какие-то библиотеки, который чуваки сели и сбацали, а про самые стандартные вещи JS. Чтобы были список свойств, методов и всех функций JS? А то я сейчас в процессе обучения, все на полной уверенности юзают разные готовые методы и функции, а я не могу понять где можно изучить список, чтобы не гуглить каждый раз есть ли готовая функция, или метод у JS на ту или иную задачу.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: гуглить все равно придется, потому что, во-первых, периодически список обновляется, во-вторых, количество методов/объектов/функций достаточно объемное, чтобы полностью выучивать.